# How do I structure the Firestore JSON of a blog API many-to-many relation

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

New to Firebase/FireStore and have no experience in `NoSQL`.

While learning Android and as well as room by building an app for myself I realized that I need a real-time database solution. But I'm stuck at building the model structure.

This is the JSON format:

```
{
 "published": "date",
 "title": "This is the title",
 "content": "This is the body",
 "tags": [
  "tag1", "tag2"
 ]
}
```

The problem is with the `tags` many-to-many relation. Realized that FireStore can solve this with indexation but how do I structure the data with Collections and Documents? Can anyone explain in details?

Comment: are tags strings or documents?

Comment: I'm getting confused now, but I think these are strings, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the snippet in your question is a `post` object, I recommend you a database schema that looks like this:

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- posts (collection)
          |
          --- postId (document)
                |
                --- published: "date"
                |
                --- title: "This is the title"
                |
                --- content: "This is the body"
                |
                --- tags
                     |
                     --- tag1: true
                     |
                     --- tag2: true
```

Accordind to the official documentation regarding [modelling data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model) in a Cloud Firestore database:

> Each document contains a set of key-value pairs. Cloud Firestore is optimized for storing large collections of small documents.

So this is the best database structure I can think of for your app and as you can see, the `tags` property is not an `array` is a `map`. This the best practice when it comes to this kind of objects. Please aslo see the offical documentation regarding [working with arrays, lists, and sets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays).

**Edit 13 Aug 2018:**

According to the updated documentation regarding [array membership](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership), now it is possible to filter data based on array values using `whereArrayContains()` method. A simple example would be:

```
CollectionReference citiesRef = db.collection("cities");
citiesRef.whereArrayContains("regions", "west_coast");
```

> This query returns every city document where the regions field is an array that contains west_coast. If the array has multiple instances of the value you query on, the document is included in the results only once.

Comment: There's an even better documentation page for this specific use-case: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays. Note that this is bound to change soon, since work is underway on set-like operations on an array.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi Puf! Isn't your link the exact same link I have added at the end of my answer? Btw, I can not wait to see the new changes :)

Comment: Woops. Yeah, missed that: I only noticed the first link. :-) Sorry about that.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank you for the quick reply. A bit skeptical about how this works, maybe a successful transaction can help me understand. Till then please stay with me.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use this

Post:

```
{
 "published": "date",
 "title": "This is the title",
 "content": "This is the body",
 "tags": [
 "xxx", "yyy"
  ]
}
```

Tags

```
[
{
    "tag_id":"xxx",
        "tag_name":"abc"
},
{
    "tag_id":"yyy",
        "tag_name":"abc"
}
]
```