# Cannot find the method whereArrayContains() for Firestore Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[Previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672302/how-do-i-structure-the-firestore-json-of-a-blog-api-many-to-many-relation) I asked a question about data model where I got a useful link for how to work with arrays [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays).

But as told by Frank van Puffelen (@FrankvanPuffelen), within the comments, there, that it will change, it changed and there is a new [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership).

But now I cannot find the method `whereArrayContains()`, e.g.:

```
CollectionReference messageRef = mFirestoreDb.collection("messages");
Query query = messageRef.whereArrayContains("...", "..."); //?
```

As for dependencies, it's up to date with [Set up your development environment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#set_up_your_development_environment) till now as I am writing this question.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It seems the documentation is ahead of the actual release.

Comment: Maybe, but generally after update the documentation is written, isn't it?

Comment: Generally, but I checked this out with the Firestore team today.  Updates are coming coming.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ok, let it "come come"  :p. However, can I ask you another question, a favor maybe? Being new to this, I mean all of these, what I understand that Firestore uses OKHttp. By any chance you guys can give us some public methods so that we can at least catch the network errors? This way we can keep track of network (without any broadcast receiver) and maybe implement a *retry button* on the **failed network call**!

Comment: If you have a new question that's unrelated to the first, please ask separately as such.

Comment: It is already in googles sample code:
https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/19680ed547e2b873971a1fddcf5770b405b532b1/firestore/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/firestore/DocSnippets.java#L988-L990

But the gradle file references "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.5" 
https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/19680ed547e2b873971a1fddcf5770b405b532b1/firestore/app/build.gradle

But 17.0.5 is nowhere to be found yet.

Comment: @Holger, the new version is live now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to solve this issue, you need to upgrade Firestore dependency to the latest version. So please change the following line of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.5'
```

And the new method that you are looking for will be available. Please see [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) more details.

Comment: Finally the new version is here, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: It's 17.1.0 tho

Comment: @FlorianWalther At the time I have answered this question, the version available for Cloud Firestore was `17.0.5`. All dependencies are constantly changing, that's why I have added that link in my answer so future visitors can use the latest version.

Comment: @AlexMamo it doesn't matter as it will change as long as the product lives; at the time I wrote the question, the method was not there but was in the document. Interesting read: "To avoid potential errors, don't use v17.0.5."